# How to not use package-info files with Hibernate UserTypes?

Tags: java, hibernate

Currently we register our user types in package-info.java files.  The classes are specified using Strings which are difficult to maintain (a simple renaming will break the code).

Like this:

```
@TypeDefs(
  {
     @TypeDef(
           name = "lienPosition",
           typeClass = EnumUserType.class,
           parameters = {
              @Parameter(name = "enum", value = "com.package.level1.LienPosition")
           }
     )
  }
```

)

Is there a way using Hibernate to register these UserTypes in a way that doesn't use Strings?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this myself, and I'm not sure it will cover your needs, but from the [hibernate 3.6 docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-registry), it looks like there is now a way to register types by a java call.  This might be something you could hook into your startup if you're running a recent enough Hibernate.  I don't believe this existed in 3.5 or earlier.

However, the discussion under this [related bug](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5138) indicates the changes made to the type system may also get in the way of your particular user types (`EnumUserType` is referenced in the discussion), so it may be you need some other changes to deal with this.